# Watir webdriver_Unable to change dropdown list in one field and verify value change in another field

Tags: webdriver, watir

Frustrated new user having difficulty.  Tried many variations and just cannot get it to work.  The html is below and I've stripped out the extra lines.  The test has to be written using this html, I cannot change it. Note, classes are named "span3".

This is a popup window that is NOT a new window, it just appears to be a new window.  The top "span3" is a dropdown list and I am trying to change the selection.  I tried using the select_list in watir, but that did not work.

In the bottom "span3", the grossmarginpercent value will be updated when I change the dropdown value in the top "span3".  I want to confirm that grossmarginpercent is updated to the correct value.

I've included the last script I tried.  I added a put because I wanted I seeing '2' on the screen, watir was returning false, and I wanted to see what watir was seeing.

watir script:

```
 grossmarginpercent = browser.div(:id => "target_modal").div(:class => "modal_body").div(:class => "row").div(:class => "span3", :index => 1).label(:id => "GrossMarginPercent")
      puts grossmarginpercent.value
             puts grossmarginpercent.value.include? '2'
```

html:

```
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span3">
                <label>Reward Type</label><select data-bind="options: $root.RewardOptions, optionsText: 'DisplayName', value: RewardOptionId, optionsValue: 'RewardOptionId'"></select>
            </div>

            <div class="span1"></div>

            <div class="span3">
                <label>Gross Margin Percent</label><label id="GrossMarginPercent" data-bind="formattedNumber: { value: GrossMarginPercent, format: '#,###.##%' }" style="padding: 6px 4px 8px 0px;"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a stab in the dark, but I would try using `Element#text` instead of `Element#value`:

```
puts grossmarginpercent.text
puts grossmarginpercent.text.include? '2'
```

I am making a couple of assumptions:

1. Given the "data-bind" attributes, I am guessing that you are using KnockoutJS (as that seems to be the most popular search result when I looked for people using data-bind attributes).
2. `formattedNumber` is a custom binding that is setting the text of the label. I assume you are trying to check something you see, which for a label element would be its text rather than its value attribute.

Comment: That worked Justin, Thanks!  Now I just need to change the value in the Reward Type dropdown list and this beast will be done.

Comment: Got my 'change dropdown list' script to work.  Thanks again for your help!